# Can you break out of strict mode in a native module?

Tags: javascript

The code in modules is in strict mode by default, but can you break out into non-strict mode, from within a module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that you should do this, but you can call `new Function`, which will not run in strict mode by default:

```html
<script type="module">
const fn = new Function('console.log(this === window);');
fn();
</script>
```

You can do something very similar with `eval`, *if* you call it by anything other than using the original reference to `window.eval`:

```html
<script type="module">
const anotherEvalReference = eval;
anotherEvalReference('console.log(this === window);');
</script>
```

(if you call `eval` from the original `window.eval` reference, it'll lexically inherit strict mode, as well as any variables in the outer scope of the `eval` call. Otherwise, if you call `eval` from a different reference, it'll run on the top level, and won't lexically inherit strict mode, or be able to reference variables outside the `eval` call, unless those variables are global)