# Javascript - Why String Mutation doesn't Throw an error?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning tricky parts of Javascript, and without judging, trying to understand how the language works, but as a developer with Java and Python background(even with Typescript) I'm struggling.

I do understand the string primitives are immutable but why this code doesn't throw an error, doesn't it make the language very error-prone?

```js
const str = "hello";
str[0] = 1;
console.log(str) // "hello"
```

Comment: It does error in strict mode

Comment: [The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable—just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its properties) can be altered.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini the fact that it is a const has no bearing on mutation, it is all down to the immutability of the string.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, you misunderstood my question I think, it's not related with const/let variable declarations. I'd ask the same question with let str = "blabla" as well.

Comment: [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3x4fsca7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript was created to be a companion scripting language to Java with a lower barrier to entry and with the then-fashionable Web Philosophy of "be forgiving of imprecise input" (cf HTML vs. XML).

So JavaScript was the product of a 1990s design philosophy that has dated poorly (hindsight!); even so, JavaScript has stood the test of time because the bones of the language were very good (compare and contrast with its competitor at the time, VBScript!). Interestingly, this was not widely understood until about 2005, leading to widespread derision that continues to this day.

Result? There are plenty of silent footguns in sloppy mode, which is an artefact of JavaScript's history; but this cannot be undone now ("don't break the Web!")

You cannot use the square bracket syntax to modify code units within a string. Whether the variable is declared with `const` or `let` is immaterial here.

In non-strict mode this fails silently (oops!): but no-one uses non-strict mode for production-facing code. ES5 (2009) introduced pragma-based opt-in strict mode that makes this an error.

ES2015 introduced modules and classes, within which all code is in strict mode ([although there are a couple of unusual tricks you can do to break out of it in exceptional cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60543172/can-you-break-out-of-strict-mode-in-a-native-module)).

```js
(() => { 
    'use strict'; 
    let str = 'hello'; 
    str[0] = 1; 
    console.log('foo'); 
})();
```